# How to conditionally send svn commit email, based on commit message keywords?

Tags: svn, email, notifications, post-commit

I've got [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) running with [svnnotify](http://search.cpan.org/~dwheeler/SVN-Notify-2.79/bin/svnnotify) sending notification email via post-commit (the common setup), but I'd like to **not send email when certain keywords are included in the commit message**, such as "#noemail" or something similar.

Anyone have an example of what I can add to my post-commit hook to look at the commit message and prevent email from being sent if certain keywords exist?

Thanks!

---

FYI, here's an example of my current post-commit content:

```
set REPOS=%1
set REV=%2
set EMAILADDRESSES="example@example.com"
set OS=Windows_NT
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;

svnnotify --repos-path %REPOS% --revision %REV% --to %EMAILADDRESSES% -f svn@example.com --smtp smtp.example.com --subject-prefix "SVN - Rev: %%d - "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution, using keyword "nosvnemail":

```
set REPOS=%1
set REV=%2
set EMAILADDRESSES="example@example.com"
set OS=Windows_NT
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;

svnlook log -r %2 %1 | FindStr "nosvnemail"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO SKIPEMAIL

svnnotify --repos-path %REPOS% --revision %REV% --to %EMAILADDRESSES% -f svn@example.com --smtp smtp.example.com --subject-prefix "SVN - Rev: %%d - "

:SKIPEMAIL

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For linux, the following `hooks/post-commit` will work:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
SVNLOOK=$(which svnlook)

LOGMSG=$($SVNLOOK log -r $REV $REPOS)
if [[ $LOGMSG != nosvnemail* ]] ; then
    "$REPOS"/hooks/mailer.py commit "$REPOS" $REV "$REPOS"/mailer.conf
fi
```

the `nosvnemail` string must be first in the log message.